# требуется ли знак препинания после "в некотором роде"

Tags: пунктуация

Следует ли отделить запятой или тире?
*В некотором роде(?) да.*

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что запятая не нужна. Выражение "в некотором роде" не является вводным словом, а других оснований для её постановки нет. Полезная информация, связанная с темой:

http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html:
Не являются вводными и не выделяются запятыми слова и словосочетания: авось, бишь, буквально, будто, вдобавок, в довершение, вдруг, ведь, ***в конечном счёте***, вот, вряд ли, всё-таки, даже, едва ли, исключительно, именно, как будто, как бы, как раз, между тем, небось, никак, почти, поэтому, приблизительно, примерно, притом, причём, просто, решительно, словно, якобы ***и др***. (частицы, наречия).

Answer (score 1):

Тире возможно как интонационный знак, запятая ничем не мотивирована.